# Getting localtime from timestamp

Tags: mysql, node.js

I've a column updated declared as `updated` TIMESTAMP and is the only TIMESTAMP type column.

When I do  `select updated from pushinfo;`

I get

```
+---------------------+
| updated             |
+---------------------+
| 2017-04-11 15:33:46 |
| 2017-04-11 15:35:02 |
| 2017-04-12 10:15:54 |
+---------------------+
```

When I use   `select FROM_UNIXTIME(updated) from pushinfo;`

I'm getting

```
| FROM_UNIXTIME(updated) |
+------------------------+
| NULL                   |
| NULL                   |
| NULL                   |
```

Why doesn't FROM_UNIXTIME work?

When I use this query

```
conn.query(' select updated from pushinfo')
```

I'm getting the updated as  something like `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.000Z`
What's the problem?

How to get in the format of HH:MM:SS YYYY-MM-DD etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FROM_UNIXTIME` expects a Unix timestamp parameter (i.e. an integer which is the number of seconds since the Unix Epoch). You have to use [DATE_FORMAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format). That is because even though the column is defined as TIMESTAMP, MySQL returns the value as a date and not as a timestamp. That's the default behaviour of MySQL for TIMESTAMP type columns. To get the actual timestamp value, you have to use [UNIX_TIMESTAMP()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp).

So your query would go like

```
conn.query(' select DATE_FORMAT(updated, "%H:%i:%s %Y-%m-%d") from pushinfo')
```

What you are getting when just selecting the `updated` column is the value of that column in the default date format of your MySQL server.

The title of your question is irrelevant from the rest of it. You will never get the local time from a Unix timestamp, because that is always in Zulu time (i.e. UTC).